# QGIS Arch Linux compilation error

Tags: qgis, python, linux

Just pulled QGIS from git and am trying to compile it, here's the relevant error:

`[ 89%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_core.dir/core/sipcorepart3.cpp.o
In file included from /home/noah/qgis/qgis-git/qgis/Quantum-GIS/python/core/qgsmaplayerregistry.sip:10:0:
/home/noah/qgis/qgis-git/qgis/Quantum-GIS/python/../src/core/qgsmaplayerregistry.h: In member function ‘virtual void sipQgsMapLayerRegistry::connectNotify(const char*)’:
/home/noah/qgis/qgis-git/qgis/Quantum-GIS/python/../src/core/qgsmaplayerregistry.h:252:10: error: ‘virtual void QgsMapLayerRegistry::connectNotify(const char*)’ is private
     void connectNotify( const char * signal );
          ^
/home/noah/qgis/qgis-git/qgis/Quantum-GIS/build-master/python/core/sipcorepart3.cpp:21714:46: error: within this context
         return;
                                              ^
make[2]: * [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_core.dir/core/sipcorepart3.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: * [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: * [all] Error 2`

I'm currently downgrading python as suggested on the AUR page-- I don't understand the problem, I hope this is the right thing to do.

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8507

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a newer SIP version (4.15). This has been reported [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8507)
This problem has been solved a moment ago in commit 641359d . Please pull and try again.